# rake db:create aborted! when upgrade gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I upgraded Ruby from 2.7.1 to 3.0.0 and rails from 6.0.3 to 6.1.0 on a new development machine.

After ran the rake db:create then I have the error bellow

rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec::Rails::Railtie::SourceAnnotationExtractor
/Users/lonh/projects/codesign/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>' /Users/lonh/projects/codesign/Rakefile:4:in` require_relative'
/Users/lonh/projects/codesign/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec::Rails::Railtie::SourceAnnotationExtractor
/Users/lonh/projects/codesign/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>' /Users/lonh/projects/codesign/Rakefile:4:in` require_relative'
/Users/lonh/projects/codesign/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

My Gemfile context is bellow

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.0'

# FOUNDATION
gem 'rails', '6.1.0'
gem 'dotenv-rails', require: 'dotenv/rails-now'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'webpacker'

# PERFORMANCE
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'dalli'
gem 'memcachier'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'sinatra', :require => nil # for sidekiq UI
gem 'sidekiq-status'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'redis-objects'
gem 'redis-namespace'

# TOOLS
gem "sentry-raven"
gem 'devise'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem 'google-webfonts', require: 'google/webfonts/rails'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6.0'
  gem "factory_bot_rails", "~> 4.10.0"
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'rename'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'database_cleaner-active_record'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 4.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My development machine is the Macbook Pro M1. I guest this might the root of the issue.

Comment: please share your cofig/application.rb file

Comment: @HafizAbdulRehman: thank for your help. I update Gemfile and application.rb

Comment: [Gemfile](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0lx-kX2dGOVwvDU2N-5CLIeWg#application)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions is update rspec to lastest version